# Xcode debugger steps over methods that execute via forwardInvocation

Tags: ios, xcode, ocmock

I noticed the following behavior when using OCMock, and after poking around I discovered it is an issue with how the Xcode debugger handles methods that are not implemented.  Here's an example:

```
@implementation ForwardingClass

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    self.delegate = [[DelegateClass alloc] init];
    return self;
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {
    [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:self.delegate];
}

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)sel {
    return [self.delegate methodSignatureForSelector:sel];
}

- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    return YES;
}

@end



@implementation DelegateClass

- (void)forwardedMethod {
    NSLog(@"got it!");
}

@end
```

Now we can call it:

```
ForwardingClass *forwardingClass = [[ForwardingClass alloc] init];

// Xcode will not step into this method
[(id)forwardingClass forwardedMethod];
```

Xcode will not step into the forwardedMethod.  Even worse, if I set a breakpoint in `forwardInvocation` it won't break there.  The net effect is that you can't step into any object that has been partially mocked by OCMock.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Is it a bug (or unintended "feature") in Xcode?
I've tried this on both Xcode 6 and Xcode 7 beta 4.

Comment: So, you are saying that if you set a breakpoint on the line `NSLog(@"got it!");` the debugger will not stop? That doesn't seem right. I have seen  issues with the debugger sending methods requesting descriptions from the object, that then retriggered `forwardInvocation:` making debugging difficult, but I can't remember seeing the problem that I think you're describing.